# Python list and dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to get use to list dictionaries comprehension. Here a small code I have not been able to transform.

```
lst = ['C', 'A', 'B', 'A']
myd = {}
for v, k in enumerate(lst):
    if k in myd:
        myd[k].append(v)
    else:
        myd[k] = [v]

print(myd)

>>> {'C': [0], 'A': [1, 3], 'B': [2]}
```

I would be please to have some help.

Comment: Well you cannot adapt this to a dictionary comprehension, and as it is very readable

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: desired output : {'C': [0], 'A': [1, 3], 'B': [2]}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer, although I think the non comprehension approach is much easier to understand.  And as mentioned this is not efficient in the least.

I would stay with what you have.

```
{k:[i for i, j in enumerate(lst) if j == k] for k in set(lst)}
```

Comment: This is bad, this O(n^2) and perhaps harder to read that the loop version

Comment: Yes, it's horrible.

Comment: Morre importantly, this is quadratic time vs the linear time naive approach

Comment: Better than this is just to sort and use itertools.groupby ....

Comment: I just wanted to improve my understanding of comprehensions. Nice Job Chris, thanks

Comment: this one works also : {k: [i for i, j in enumerate(lst) if j == k] for k in lst})

Comment: Idea by @DaniMesejo: `{k: [p[1] for p in g] for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted((ch, i) for i, ch in enumerate(lst)), key=lambda p: p[0])}`

Answer (score 1):

A hack with a helper dict, but at least it's linear time.

```
>>> {k: d.setdefault(k, []).append(i) or d[k]
     for d in [{}]
     for i, k in enumerate(lst)}
{'C': [0], 'A': [1, 3], 'B': [2]}
```

A variation:

```
>>> {k: d.setdefault(k, [i])
     for d in [{}]
     for i, k in enumerate(lst)
     if k not in d or d[k].append(i)}
{'C': [0], 'A': [1, 3], 'B': [2]}
```

Comment: Thanks, also a nice solution, maybe easier to understand